# Why does project reactor hang indefinitely when switchIfEmpty is used?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

**Background**

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.1, project-reactor 3.3.0 and spring-data-mongodb 2.2.1 and I'm trying to load data from multiple queries. My code looks roughly like this:

```
Flux.just("type1", "type2", "type3", "type4")
    .concatMap { type ->
        reactiveMongoOperations.find<Map<String, Any>>(BasicQuery("{'type': '$type'}"), "collectionName")
                                .doOnError { e ->
                                    log.error("Caught exception when reading from mongodb: ${e::class.simpleName} - ${e.message}", e)
                                }.switchIfEmpty {
                                    log.warn("Failed to find any documents of type $type")
                                    Mono.empty<Map<String, Any>>()
                                }
    } 
    .. // More operations here
    .subscribe()
```

The problem is that if `reactiveMongoOperations.find(..)` doesn't find any documents for a given type (and thus `"Failed to find any documents of type $type"` is logged) the entire operation will just hang indefinitely. If I remove the `switchIfEmpty` clause the operations completes and everything works fine.

**Questions**

1. Why does the entire operation just hang if I add the `switchIfEmpty` operation? It doesn't matter if I use `flatMap` instead of `concatMap`, it will hang eventually anyways.
2. How should I log that no documents are found for the particular query? I.e. I want to log that no documents were found when `reactiveMongoOperations.find(..)` returns an empty `Flux`.

Comment: Your code looks very strange with all the brackets, please update your question with correct runnable code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I think its correct, it's Kotlin though. I'm thinking that Kotlin is quite ubiquitous, but I should probably change to plain Java to make it easier for Java devs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When re-writing the code to Java from Kotlin (as suggested by Thomas in the comment) I found the answer! I had assumed that I used the Kotlin `reactor.kotlin.core.publisher.switchIfEmpty` extension function provided by the `reactor-kotlin-extensions` library:

```
fun <T> Flux<T>.switchIfEmpty(s: () -> Publisher<T>): Flux<T> = this.switchIfEmpty(Flux.defer { s() })
```

This was not the case here and thus I ended up using the `switchIfEmpty` method defined in `Flux` defined like this:

```java
public final Flux<T> switchIfEmpty(Publisher<? extends T> alternate)
```

To make it work without the extension function I should probably have done something like this:

```
.. 
.switchIfEmpty { subscriber ->
    log.warn("Failed to find any documents of type $type")
    subscriber.onComplete()
}
```

My initial solution didn't work because the Java version assumes that I *create* a `Publisher` (which I did) and also *invoke* a function on this publisher (which I didn't). In Kotlin the lambda parameter is optional, if you don't need it, which is why the type-system didn't catch this.

This is one way that Kotlin interop with Java can be tricky.